Connection between number of "ascents" and "progressive elements" in permutations
As mentioned in this question: Number of Permutation with Pro = k equals the Eulerian Number A(n,k+1), the number of permutations of $n$ numbers with $k$ "progressive elements" (element larger than the position index number) is the Eulerian number $\left< \begin{array}{c} n \\ k \end{array} \right>$, which is the number of permutations with $k$ "ascents" (element larger than the previous element). [Note that $A(n, k+1)$ in this question is using the notation by Comtet: $A(n, k+1) = \left< \begin{array}{c} n \\ k \end{array} \right>$, instead of the more common $A(n, k) = \left< \begin{array}{c} n \\ k \end{array} \right>$]. An answer to this question proves this by proving that the number of permutations with "# progressive elements=$k$" satisfies the same recursive relationship as the number of permutations with "# ascents=$k$". The fact that the number of permutations with "# progressive elements=$k$" is the same as the number of permutations with "# ascents=$k$" is amazing, I wonder if there is a deeper connection between the two. Is there a way to establish a direct relationship between them, $e.g.$ establishing a one-to-one mapping, so we can prove this fact directly, without resorting to the recursive relationship for "progressive elements"?

Indeed there is! The following argument is from Stanley's Enumerative Combinatorics volume I, proposition 1.3.12 (1.4.3 in the second edition). I'll write in some detail as I'm not sure what your background is.
Let $S_n$ be the set of permutations of $[n] = \{1,\dots,n\}$. The idea of the bijection $S_n \to S_n$ that we will use (ie, that takes permutations with '# progressive $= k$' to those with '# ascents $= k$) is that we can see elements of $S_n$ in two ways, as functions $[n] \to [n]$ or as words in the alphabet $[n]$. This bijection (which Staley calls the "standard form" of a permutation) is useful for all sorts of bijective proofs.
Given a permutation $\pi:[n] \to [n]$, define a word $\hat\pi$ as follows: write $\pi$ in cycle notation, then arrange each cycle with its largest element first, and arrange the cycles in increasing order of these largest elements, then erase parentheses. EG if $\pi \in S_7$ is (as a word) $4271365$, then its standard form is $(2)(41)(6)(753)$ and $\hat\pi = 2416753$. $\pi$ can be recovered from $\hat\pi$ by inserting parentheses at each left-to-right maximum (or "record").
Now we will observe that, if $\pi \in S_n$ has standard form
$$ \pi = (a_1a_2\cdots a_{i_1})(a_{i_1+1}\cdots a_{i_2})\cdots(a_{i_{k-1}+1}\cdots a_n)$$
then $\pi(a_j) \ge a_j$ iff $a_j < a_{j+1}$ or $i=n$. This is clear if $\pi(a_j) = a_{j+1}$ ("inside the cycle"), and it's also true if $j=i_{m}$, since the largest elements of each cycle are listed first.
This implies the "weakly progressive" elements ($i$ so that $\pi(i)\ge i$) of $\pi$ are $n$ correspond to the ascents of $\hat\pi$. Then note that
$$ \{i\mid \pi(i) \ge i\} = \{i \mid \pi^{-1}(i) \le i\} = [n] \setminus \{i \mid \pi^{-1}(i) > i\}, $$
so that $\pi$ has $k$ weakly progressive elements iff $\pi^{-1}$ has $n-k$ progressive elements. Also, $\hat\pi = a_1\cdots a_n$ has $k$ ascents iff $\mathop{rev}(\hat\pi) = a_n\cdots a_1$ has $n-k+1$ ascents, so finally
$$ \{\pi \mid \pi^{-1}\text{ has } k \text{ progressive elements}\} = \{\pi\mid \mathop{rev}(\hat\pi) \text{ has } k+1 \text{ ascents}\}. $$

Beautiful! Thanks.
Which edition of Stanley's book do you have? In the second edition, proposition 1.3.12 is the following proposition about inversion table:
1.3.12 Proposition. Let
$$
T_n = {(a_1, . . ., a_n) : 0 ≤ a_i ≤ n − i} = [0, n − 1] × [0, n − 2] × · · · × [0, 0].
$$
The map $I : S_n → T_n$ that sends each permutation to its inversion table is a bijection.

right! good pickup — in the second (much expanded! it seems) edition it's prop. 1.4.3
